# Enforce collocation of data in the region where it is used

Tags: architecture, database-design

How to make sure that data specific to particular region remains in the closest data center to ensure low latency?

Lets consider Amazon e-commerce as an example . It sells products all over the world and not every product and product's seller is available in every region. So there is no point in showing , lets say ABC speakers which are not sold in Australia, to customers in Europe.

So if the user in Australia wants to list all the speakers , a simple query `where country='AUSTRALIA'`  will work ( in the simplest case)

**Question 1:**

Next comes how to resolve the latency part ( where my question is). How do we ensure that products   sold in Australia are the only one that are present in Australian data center's database. Because, if we fire the above query the partition ( or even the replica of the partition ) that carry the information about product =Speaker and country =Australia might be present in Japan.

As per my understanding,  Amazon or such eCommerce will probably have elastic search DB  cluster which is geographically spread and partitioning on key = country will  not answer the question.

**Question 2:**

Is it a good idea to maintain separate database for each country to solve above issue?

This question even extends to Uber. Uber keeps track of all the rides that are available within all the regions of the world ( where Uber is actually available) in its Redis cluster. Now when a user wants to search for a ride in region-1 it will not be a good idea to send this request to USA because the partition that is handling the region of Australia is actually present in USA.

Can you please give some idea of how to make sure data is collocated with the region it is used in?

**EDIT 1**

In the below image you can see layout of the application and structure of product table. Basically DB cluster consist of Server S1, S2, S3 and partition is denoted by p* and Data Center is denoted by DC*

Assume the products Sony and Bose will map to partition p1.

In the diagram the user request has landed to DC-AUS (Data center Australia) but the products that are available in Australia are mapped to partition 1 which is present in Japan and USA.

[image]

Comment: Dns can be used for latency control (if the request ip is from Japan, answer with the ip for the data center in Japan) . But impossible to answer what you need to do, as there is no information about what kind of data are you going to deliver and/or collect

Comment: "partitioning on key = country will not answer the question"  Why not?

Comment: @candied_orange If my database cluster (replication factor =2) contains server S1 ( in USA) , S2 (in UK), S3( in Japan) and S4( in Australia) then one of the partition (lets say partition = AUSTRALIA)  of the products table could be present in Japan and USA

Comment: @MrZach understood that proximity based dns routing will ensure user request will lend to closest data center ( hence database) . But the database partition can be present in any server of the cluster. And the partition that carry Australian product information might be present in the server in Japan.

Comment: @StackManaged sounds like you have two fields: stockCountry and hostCountry. No reason to replicate the hostCountry field.

Comment: @candied_orange I have updated my question (from edit 1)  . Hopefully it remove the confusion . There are only two fields in productName and country

Comment: @StackManaged So Australian products are mapped to partition 1, which doesn't exist in the Australian Data Center.  What problem are you solving by doing it that way?

Comment: @candied_orange if partition 1 would have existed in Australia data center then we can reduce latency. Now in above case request from Australia data center read server would have to go to Japan Data center to fetch the Australian products

Comment: For "closest server", don't focus too much om geography. Internet connectivity can be weird in that New York (USA) is geographically further from Amsterdam (NED) than Berlin(GER), but in internet connectivity it can be closer.

Comment: I understand the closest server or Proximity based routing will ensure to take me to 
@BartvanIngenSchenau closest data center ( And most of the time if you are requesting from Australia your request won't land in USA). Once I am in the  "closest" data center , if my data set is not present in the closest data center my database request will need to go to different data center. Correct ? That doesn't sound right .

Comment: Unless you use different URLs for different countries, you can never be 100% sure that your customer will land at the datacentre you expected. When they hit the "wrong" datacentre, what would you prefer? A slightly degraded performance because the data has to be retrieved externally or telling the customer that you can't help them. And also consider use-cases like a customer in the USA who wants to make a purchase for someone in Australia. They would probably prefer to see item available in Australia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do we ensure that products sold in Australia are the only one that are present in Australian data center's database.

you can have different URLs (sites) for different country . E.g: amazon.com.au

Going beyond the question: This way you can also follow country specific regulation. E.g: A database ( or any  software ) need to have certain specific patch installed for auditing or compliance purpose.

> Because, if we fire the above query the partition ( or even the replica of the partition ) that carry the information about product =Speaker and country =Australia might be present in Japan.

No, it would be present in Australia's data center as well because you can have following option

1. you will have different URL (and database) for each country.
   OR
2. You will have complete replica of database in **each** data center. This mean each partition will be present in every data center. e.g : if your eCommerce db supports all country AUS, JAP, US, UK  and you decided to have just one DB ( composed to servers and partition). The same DB (replica) will be present in each of the country's data center.

> Now when a user wants to search for a ride in region-1 it will not be a good idea to send this request to USA because the partition that is handling the region of Australia is actually present in USA.

As mentioned, the request will be sent to the closest data center which will contain the complete copy of database.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are conflating two separate issues here

1. How do restrict items so they can only be sold to customers residing in particular countries

   This is easy enough, work out where the customer resides, either by geolocating their IP or examining their payment or delivery information and compare that to the list of countries for the products.
2. How do I optimise my traffic so that customers use a copy of my website which is hosted geographically close to them

   This is more complex, but there are several commercial products you can buy off the (cloud) shelf. Or more simply you can just have a different URL for each country.

Now, your final question

3. Should each country specific site have the same database?

   This is more complex and depends on your business.

- A Clothing retailer for example may  not want to sell winter coats to Australians in summer. (bizarrely some *do* want to because fashion),

  They might have a completely different dataset for each season and each region
- Fidget Spinners Inc might want to sell the same thing at the same price to everyone in the world

  They can just replicate their dataset globally
- Computer Games Ltd might want to sell the same game but at a different price depending on where the customer is.

  They might want the same dataset but with region specific fields

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding the point  1, I am not trying to figure out which product is available in which region. Lets say I know that. I have also edited my question from "edit 1". I want data relevant for the user to be closest to his data center. So if Sony headphone are only sold in Australia, I would like to make sure that the corresponding record must be present in the Australia data center (to reduce latency). Can you please tell me more about point 2. What are these products called or any example of such product.

Comment: Your point 3, is precisely my question. Should we go for the response that I suggested in "question 2". Given the distinction in data set for each country (in simplest case Sony headphones are only sold in Australia) then this data ideally should be present in the closest data center of Australia ( helps in latency). What should I do to ensure this?  Is separate database for each country a solution ?

Comment: you arent making much sense. why would the headphones ever _not_ be in the austrailian db

Comment: Can you please point where I mentioned that headphones shouldn't be in Australia DB?  I am asking how to make sure headphones are close to Australian data center

Comment: just put them in the database? im asking why you think they would **NOT** be there

Comment: so at which step I am going wrong. 1)  DB is composed of several database server to form a cluster.  (2) each server will be present in one of the DC [data center]. (3) DB is also divided into partitions. (4) a given record -Sony will map to only one partition -p1. (5) [ assume replication factor =2].A partition will be present in only 2 DB server and hence only 2 data center.  (6) If request lands on DC-AUS (which doesn't have partition -p1 ) db select statement will get data from p1 which is in DC-JAP and hence increase in latency.

Comment: 1 and 3 i think. dont try and make a distributed database, just have a copy of the db in each location